# concatenate numpy arrays from different Dataframe Columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas data frame including some columns, let say 'a', 'b' and 'c', containing numpy arrays.

I would like to concatenate the np arrays from different columns obtaining a single np array for each row.

Is there an efficient way to do this avoiding iteration?

Comment: Each cell array is separate.  Look for example at `df['a'].to_numpy()`.  I expect it is a 1d object dtype array.  If the subarrays are all the same size, they can be `stack` into one 2d array.  But if different, you are stuck with working on separate arrays.  This needs a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can concat two NumPy arrays with np.concatenate function.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [np.array([1]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
df['y'] = [np.array([1]), np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]
df['concat'] = df[['x', 'y']].apply(lambda x:  np.concatenate((x[0], x[1])), axis=1)
```

df

```
           x          y              concat
0        [1]        [1]              [1, 1]
1     [1, 2]     [1, 2]        [1, 2, 1, 2]
2  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `apply` is a row iteration, but since the cell arrays are all different, I don't think there's a way around this.